# possible to shrink toolbar area when setting tools to [] in kendo editor

Tags: kendo-ui, editor

Solved (see my comment):

With the setting `tools : []` in the Editor configuration, the editor displays no tools in the toolbar area,  as expected, but the toolbar area does not collapse, and remains the same height as if there were tool icons being displayed. Is there a way to shrink the (empty) toolbar height using CSS?

P.S. The text content must remain editable. I'm not looking for a way to make it "read only".

Comment: The toolbar area does collapse for me when there are no tools. ([Sample](http://dojo.telerik.com/ORApi)) Can you reproduce that behavior in a runnable Dojo?

Comment: Just found my issue. In the `resizable` property I had `{content: true, toolbar: true}.`  Thanks for confirming that it works as I thought it should.